# Unable to understand the working of PHP recursive function

Tags: php

I find it difficult to understand the working of this recursive function in PHP. I am not able to follow the code written at return statement. How the total of numbers from 1 to 10 is added? I eagerly want to understand this line `return $count + sum($count + 1);`

My whole code is:

```
<?php
function sum($count)
{
    if($count <= 10)
    {
        echo $count;
        echo "<br />";
        return $count + sum($count + 1);
    }
}
$result = sum(1);
echo "The total is $result";
?>
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
The total is 55
```

How the total 55 is received in my code? I want to learn it step by step.

Comment: "I want to learn it step by step" — Step though it with a debugger.

Comment: Write it out step by step with pen and paper.

Comment: @DavidPartyka NO, i don't want loop, only recursion

Answer (score 0):

Define the function

```
 function sum($count)
 {
```

Check if $count <=10 so the function will not excuted if

```
$count > 10 
if($count <= 10)
{
```

Print $count followed by a line break

```
    echo $count;
    echo "<br />";
```

Return $count + the result of the same function for $count+1 this which make the function work until reach the if condition $count<=10

```
    return $count + sum($count + 1);
    }
}
```

Note that while you pass 1 as a parameter and the function call itself within it so it will be continues until it reaches 10
    $result = sum(1);
    echo "The total is $result";
    ?>

Comment: the return line that i couldn't understand and that's why i asked this question is still unanswered. what is the result of sum($count + 1) when the function is executed first time i.e. when $count = 1?

Comment: you said `Return $count + the result of the same function for $count+1` what is the result of sum() at first call. i mean return $count + sum($count + 1)

Comment: how the addition concatenation works here?

Comment: you explained unnecessary steps here. those are already understood. can you please explain the return sum concatenation plz.